# How to prove this using resolution theorem or resolution refutation?

Tags: logic

I need to prove $\{P \vee (Q \wedge R), S \} \models (S \wedge P) \vee Q$ using resolution theorem or resolution refutation. This is my proof:

1. Convert $P \vee (Q \wedge R)$ to $(P \vee Q) \wedge (P \wedge R)$
2. Convert conclusion to $(S \vee Q ) \wedge (P \vee Q)$
3. Negate conclusion $\neg((S \vee Q ) \wedge (P \vee Q))$
4. De Morgan's law to conclusion $\neg(S \vee Q) \vee \neg(P \vee Q)$
5. De Morgan's Law again to conclusion $(\neg S \wedge \neg Q) \vee (\neg P \wedge \neg Q)$

After this I am lost what to do next. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the **conjunctive normal form** for $P\vee(Q\wedge R)$ is $(P\vee Q)\wedge (P\vee R)$

The CNF for $S$ is of course, $S$.

And your work at finding the CNF for the negation of the conclusion is okay so far.†   Next *distribute* $(\neg S \wedge \neg Q) \vee (\neg P \wedge \neg Q)$ to obtain its CNF: $(\neg S\vee \neg P)\wedge\neg Q$.

So you just need to resolve $\{(P,Q),(P,R),S,(\neg S,\neg P),\neg Q\}$ to a contradiction.

$~$

---

† Though it would have been easier to just *negate the DNF* into a CNF using de Morgan's rule twice.  $\neg((S\wedge P)\vee Q)=(\neg S\vee\neg P)\wedge\neg Q$ with no need to convert, negate, then convert again.